# Eclipse Android Development - [I18N] Hardcoded string "TextView", should use @string resource

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, sdk

I am new to android developmentand tried creating a new layout named new_layout.xml which I actually saw in a Lynda training course with the code below and it worked fine. But every time I close off Eclipse and the AVD and start it up later I get some errors in the xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />  <!-- [I18N] Hardcoded string "TextView", should use @string resource  -->

<EditText   <!-- This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint -->
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   <!-- Use a layout_width of 0dp instead of wrap_content for better performance -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Here is a screenshot of the other errors that suddenly appeared:
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse is encouraging you to use the `strings.xml` file to declare strings instead of hard-coding them into other project files, like you are doing.

The `strings.xml` file can be found in `res/values/strings.xml` in your project. Simply place your strings in this file like shown in [this example](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicNetworking/res/values/strings.html), and reference those strings in your other project files.

Here's an example of what it might look like:
**new_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/textView" />  <!-- [I18N] Hardcoded string "TextView", should use @string resource  -->

<EditText   <!-- This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint -->
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   <!-- Use a layout_width of 0dp instead of wrap_content for better performance -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button" />
```

**res/values/strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="textView">TextView</string>
    <string name="button">Button</string>
</resources>
```

Since the screenshot is not correctly linked, I only have the title to go off of, so hopefully this helps.

Comment: thanks.  that helped.  I also figured out how to get rid of the <!-- This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint --> issue by using android:inputType="text"

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoded strings, missing content description and so on are no errors, but `Lint` *warnings* related to usability of your application. Consult the [lint docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html) to find out more.

Example: you can place the same String into `/res/values` and (for example) `/res/values-de` folders. If the device language is German, the system will take the string from the folder qualified with `-de`. Hardcoding a string means it will remain the same no matter of device settings.

It's not an error, but *a matter of usability*. Same applies to all `Lint` warnings.

Comment: Thanks. I will will check out the Lint docs as I am not familiar with it.